# Keras CNN: Syntax When Validation Dataset Does Not Include All Class

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I am building a convolutional neural network using a very unbalanced dataset. The dataset is about 15k images with about 5k unique labels.

Some images appear many times, but some images only appear once. Since some images only appear once, they can't appear in both the training and validation dataset.

I chose to include all the labels that only appear once in the train set. Consequently, the test set has at least 1 image from all 5k labels. However, the test set only contains images from roughly 2.5K labels.

I am feeding batches of images to the model using keras flow_from_dataframe. The dataframe contains two columns, one for the image name and one for the image ID. The image iD is a numerical value (i.e. 1 - 5k). Both the train and validation dataset include the maximum label.

The training process fails since not all classes are represented in the validations set.

To setup the training generator, I am using the following syntax.

```
train_generator = data_generator.flow_from_dataframe(
        dataframe=train_xnw_t,
        directory=train_dir,
        x_col="Image", 
        y_col="num_id",
        has_ext=True,
        target_size=(image_size, image_size),
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode='categorical',
        seed = 0)
```

I am setting up the validation data generator using the following syntax.

```
validation_generator = data_generator.flow_from_dataframe(
        dataframe=train_xnw_v,
        directory=train_dir,
        x_col="Image", 
        y_col="num_id",
        has_ext=True,
        target_size=(image_size, image_size),
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode='categorical')
```

I am fitting the model as follows.

```
epochs = 10
history=model.fit_generator(generator=train_generator, 
                            steps_per_epoch= train_generator.n//batch_size, 
                            validation_data = validation_generator,
                            validation_steps =  validation_generator.n//batch_size,
                            epochs=epochs)
```

I get this error.

```
Error when checking target: expected dense to have shape (5004,) but got array with shape (2931,)
```

Conceptually, I understand why but there must be a way to tell the model that not all classes are represented in the validation set. Does anyone know how to do so?

Comment: How on earth do you plan to train a network to recognise 5k labels with only 15k training samples?

Comment: One shot learning Karl ....  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-shot_learning

Comment: Have you tried handing over `train_xnw_t` in a one-hot encoded format, instead of just with the two columns? The keras documentation seems to suggest that this would be supported: "dataframe: Pandas dataframe containing the filenames of the  images in a column and classes in another or column/s that can be fed as raw target data". Also see the `subset` argument. If that doesn't work: I've never used `flow_from_dataframe` but I've done a lot of tinkering with `flow_from_directory` and its underlying inputs/outputs. It isn't hard to create a custom iterator that overrides how y data is generated

Comment: I don't think you can do one-shot learning without a model more sophisticated than the plain CNN used for, well, *not* one-shot learning.

Comment: Just using this as a baseline

Comment: @ZakRaySick Were you able to solve? If yes, then How?